# Create javascript json object on iteration jsp bean using jstl c:forEach

Tags: javascript, json, jsp

**I have two java class as**

```
public class Abc{
   private List<SomeOtherClass> someClass;
   private String k;
   private String m;
}

public class SomeOtherClass{
   private String a;
   private String b;
   private String c;

}
```

**I have a jsp page where I am creating bean of class Abc**

```
<jsp:useBean id="someId" class="Abc" scope="request" />
```

Now in this jsp and inside a script tag I am trying to create a javascript array of json objects

```
<script>
 var abc = (function(){
     module._myFunction = {
             "key1" :"<c:out value = '${someId.k}'/>",
             "key2" :{
                      <c:forEach varStatus='status' items='${someId.someClass}' var ="xyz">
                          "subKey1":"${xyz.a}",
                          "subKey2":${xyz.b}
                      </c:forEach>
                    }
              }
}(abc || {}))

</script>
```

But this snippet is throwing an error of "Unexpected string " because of the code inside the c:forEach loop. But if I omit the subkey1 & subKey2 it is working fine. Also I think this is expected. Is there any way I can create this json array .
And when I am checking abc.key1 is developers tool it is giving right value. 
Is there any way I can create this json array and check

```
abc.key2.subkey1 or abc.key2.subKey2  in developer console
```

Answer (score 0):

If there were 3 items in your list and you were to expand this portion of your code:

```
"key2" :{
    <c:forEach varStatus='status' items='${someId.someClass}' var ="xyz">
        "subKey1":"${xyz.a}",
        "subKey2":${xyz.b}
    </c:forEach>
}
```

it would look like:

```
"key2" :{
        "subKey1":"a",
        "subKey2":b
        "subKey1":"1",
        "subKey2":2
        "subKey1":"y",
        "subKey2":z
}
```

which is not a validly formatted json array.   (See here for a quick example of a valid JSON array: http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp -- scroll down to "JSON Arrays")

What you want it to look like is:

```
"key2" :[
        {
             "subKey1":"a",
             "subKey2":"b"
        },
        {
            "subKey1":"1",
            "subKey2":"2"
        },
        {
            "subKey1":"y",
            "subKey2":"z"
        }
 ]
```

So you need braces around each element, a comma after the braces if it is not the last element, and the entire thing surrounded by brackets. Here is how you would do that:

```
"key2" : [
    <c:forEach varStatus='status' items='${someId.someClass}' var ="xyz">
        {
            "subKey1":"${xyz.a}",
            "subKey2":"${xyz.b}"
        }<c:if test="${!status.last}">,</c:if>
    </c:forEach>
]
```

Note: I did not test this to make sure my example is free of typos, so let me know if you get any errors and I will tell you how to fix it.